# Как правильно инвертировать собственный фильтр в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Я написал свой фильтр на проверку админа из базы данных:

```
class IsAdmin:
    def __call__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        """
        :return: bool
        """
        return db.reference(f'users/{message.from_user.id}/role/admin').get() is True

    def __invert__(self, message: Message) -> bool:
        """
        :return: bool
        """
        return db.reference(f'users/{message.from_user.id}/role/admin').get() is False
```

Но когда я использую:

```
@dp.message(~IsAdmin())
```

Вылетает ошибка, что нужно передать `message`, окей

```
@dp.message(lambda msg: ~IsAdmin(msg))
```

И ничего не работает, без ошибок

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте убрать ```is True``` в ```__call__```, и в ```__invert__``` заменить ```return <expression> is False``` на ```return not <expression>```

Comment: @Gawain нет, не помогло, но у меня немного другим способом через `__init__` получилось, не знаю, будет ли называться это костылём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему вот так

```
class IsAdmin:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.message = msg

    def __call__(self) -> bool:
        """
        :return: bool
        """
        return db.reference(f'users/{self.message.from_user.id}/role/admin').get() is True

    def __invert__(self) -> bool:
        """
        :return: bool
        """
        return db.reference(f'users/{self.message.from_user.id}/role/admin').get() is False
```

```
@dp.message(lambda msg: ~IsAdmin(msg))
```